# Serilog with Elasticsearch sink, indexformat has no rolling date

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, serilog

I use Serilog with the Elasticsearch sink to push my logs into Elastic, as well as my transactions in APM in a .net 5 application.

When the Logger is created, it use the current datetime as part of the indexformat (mslogs-yyyy.MM.dd) but as soon as the container is running, this is still the same index name that is used, regardless of the current time.
For example if a container is started on 2021/06/25, the index is created as `mslogs-2021.06.25` and it's kept for the whole lifetime of the container, so logs beeing produced on following days are still pushed in that index.

As my Ops put policies on Elk to remove old logs, based on index name (datetime part) fresh logs may be removed because they are put into an "old index".

[image: Exemple of logs from Jun 30 2021 pushed into mslogs-2021.06.28 (start date of the container that has never reboot until now)]

Here is my Logger builder

```c#
    public static Logger GetELKLogger(IConfiguration config, string varEnv = "ElasticSearchLog")
    {
        var configuration = config.Get<Configuration>(varEnv);

        return new LoggerConfiguration()
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(config)
        .Enrich.WithElasticApmCorrelationInfo()
        .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri(configuration.ElasticSearchLog))
        {
            AutoRegisterTemplate = true,
            IndexFormat = $"mslogs-{DateTime.UtcNow:yyyy.MM.dd}", // called once at startup !!
            DetectElasticsearchVersion = true,
            RegisterTemplateFailure = RegisterTemplateRecovery.IndexAnyway,
            AutoRegisterTemplateVersion = AutoRegisterTemplateVersion.ESv7,
            FailureCallback = e => Console.WriteLine($"Unable to submit event {e.RenderMessage()} to ElasticSearch. Full message : " + e.Serialize()),
            EmitEventFailure = EmitEventFailureHandling.WriteToSelfLog |
                                    EmitEventFailureHandling.WriteToFailureSink |
                                    EmitEventFailureHandling.RaiseCallback,
            BufferCleanPayload = (failingEvent, statuscode, exception) =>
            {
                dynamic e = JObject.Parse(failingEvent);
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Dictionary<string, object>()
                    {
                        { "action", "DeniedByElasticSearch"},
                        { "@timestamp",e["@timestamp"]},
                        { "level","Error"},
                        { "message","Error: "+e.message},
                        { "messageTemplate",e.messageTemplate},
                        { "failingStatusCode", statuscode},
                        { "failingException", exception}
                    });
            },
            CustomFormatter = new EcsTextFormatter()
        })
        .CreateLogger();
    }
```

and the logger creation

```c#
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Logger
            Log.Logger = SharedLibraries.Logging.LoggerFactory.GetELKLogger(Configuration);
```

Should I force the logger instance to be recreated once a day to benefit from the `DateTime.UtcNow` updating ?
Or is there any more elegant solution ?

Dependencies

```xml
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>

    <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Hosting" Version="4.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.ElasticSearch" Version="8.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Seq" Version="5.0.1" />

    <PackageReference Include="Elastic.Apm.NetCoreAll" Version="1.11.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Elastic.Apm.SerilogEnricher" Version="1.5.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Elastic.CommonSchema.Serilog" Version="1.5.3" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `IndexFormat` property is [a .NET format string](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-elasticsearch/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch/Sinks/ElasticSearch/ElasticsearchSinkOptions.cs#L104) over the event's timestamp (in UTC), so you shouldn't use `$` to interpolate the value:

```cs
IndexFormat = "mslogs-{0:yyyy.MM.dd}"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I completely missed the fact that a template string is supposed to be supplied to let Serilog interpolate it, and not an already interpolated string which is a kind of const obviously. My bad!